# Stopping Android services from an extended Application class

Tags: java, android, service

I'm having some troubles trying to stop a services which I started previously on the onCreate() of class that is extended of an Android Application class. The GPS is supposed to be running during the execution of the app (that part is working fine) but when the app is closed the service is still running. I tried to use the onTerminate() because onClose() doesn´t exist in Applicaction class and the service keep running.

```
   public class ControlEntrega extends Application {

    public GPSBean posicion;
    public ServicioGPS servicio;

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
        usuario=null;
        cliente=null;
        entrega=null;
        dal=new DAL(getApplicationContext());
        crearDB();
        util=new Utilitario();
        servicio=new ServicioGPS();
        posicion=new GPSBean();
        iniciarGPS();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        Log.d(TAG,"onTerminate");
        try {
            stopService(new Intent(this,ServicioGPS.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onTerminate error: "+e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
```

The Service Class:

public class ServicioGPS extends Service implements LocationListener{

```
String TAG=ServicioGPS.class.getCanonicalName();
LocationManager locationManager=null;
public int tiempoGPS=1;
public int distanciaMetros=10;
Intent notificacion;
ControlEntrega controlador;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    controlador= (ControlEntrega)getApplicationContext();
    if(controlador!=null){
        if(controlador.posicion!=null){
            controlador.posicion.imprimir();
        }
    }
    locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

    //LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
    //LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1000 * 60 * tiempoGPS,distanciaMetros,this);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged");

    //Seteando los valores del objeto location
    if(controlador!=null){
        Log.d(TAG, "seteando bean GPS");
        controlador.posicion=new GPSBean();
        controlador.posicion.latitud=location.getLatitude();
        controlador.posicion.longitud=location.getLongitude();
        controlador.posicion.altitud=location.getAltitude();
        controlador.posicion.precision=location.getAccuracy();
        controlador.posicion.proveedor=location.getProvider();
        controlador.posicion.tiempo=location.getTime();
        controlador.posicion.velocidad=location.getSpeed();
        controlador.posicion.imprimir();
    }

    //Notificación
    Intent notificacion = new Intent(getString(R.string.intentGPS));
    sendBroadcast(notificacion);

    //Se para asi mismo, ya se calendarizo antes
    stopSelf();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

  }
```

There is a way I could know when the application stops completely? So I can stop the service.

Regards

Alfredo

Comment: Is your service running in different process than the application you used for starting service. please check the manifest declaration of ServicioGPS.

Comment: Is your onTerminate ever being called? Actually, to be safe, you should change things in onPause() because your process can be killed by the OS after it calls onPause(). This implies that onStop() and onDestroy() may or may not be called.
In any case, there is no guarantee that onDestroy() will ever be called. If the OS decides to kill your process it won't bother calling onDestroy() on any activities.

Comment: Regarding the "is there  away to know if my stops completely" You need to write a file and update this file in each activity life-cycle method then you have to track this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EyeCastApplication extends Application {

    static Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    /***
     * start Heart Beat Loop
     */
public static void stopHeartBeatLoop() {
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, CmdConnectService.class));
    }



enter code here

    enter code here

}
```